# How to Have Lots of Moving Widgets in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, widget

I know there are game/sprite engines written for Flutter, but my goal is to better understand painting and widgets, so I want to do this myself.

If I wanted a bunch of small widgets that could move around on a gameboard, what would be the best way to do this? Would I just create a box widget with fixed dimensions and have a bunch of children where I could control their position?

One example would be having a playing area with scrabble tiles that could be moved around.  Or Tetris blocks falling.  Different widgets that can be anywhere and that can be moved.  I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: I thought about just drawing everything, but wouldn't the entire set of shapes have to be redrawn if any of them change? I thought widgets would be more efficient because only changed ones would have to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw custom shapes and lines using canvas in flutter and then animate them as flutter supports 60 frames per second. You need to understand customPaint very well. Here is a great demonstration of how to use customPaint to draw custom shapes.

https://medium.com/@rjstech/flutter-custom-paint-tutorial-build-a-radial-progress-6f80483494df